# What is the purpose of Facebook app access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm currently working on a website for my friend and I'm trying to embed his Facebook page reviews into the website.

I've already spent significant amount of time reading about the tokens, but I'm still struggling to understand something.

What is the purpose of App Access Token, if, to fetch anything I still need to use my User Access Token to get the Page Access token? Am I missing something or is this actually how this works?

Why I'm so concerned, is because I want to fetch the data in the back-end, and even if I use the extended User token, at some point it will expire. What's then? I'm not planning to use FB JS SDK, because I don't need any users visiting website to login, what would then be needed for the back-end to be able to refresh the token?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To whoever is struggling with the same scenario, there seems to be a solution.

1. Generate a User Access Token
2. Extend the User Access Token
3. Call `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={your_extended_user_access_token}`
4. Find the page you're interested in the response, and copy the access token.

Checking the access token in the debugger tool now shows that it never expires.
I haven't tested if it for sure never expires (i.e. what would happen if I'm removed as a page admin).

Also, the debugger tool says that Data Access will expire in 3 months. As per documentation, the permissions I need shouldn't need reauthorization so fingers crossed it actually won't.

Although I found the answer to my problem, the original question as to what's the purpose of App Access Token is still unclear to me. Documentation says I should be able to replace user access token with app access token, that's not true or again, I'm missing something.